# Mobile close vote view completely broken on duplicate

Tags: bug

I close voted a question as "duplicate" this morning on my Nexus 4 - the view is really screwed up.

I can't get a good picture right now but the view has a few weird things on it:

- Vote count width is really narrow (1 character) so the list of votes is vertical, not horizontal
- The red frame around the previews is really wide with a huge white space on the right
- The "back to similar questions" link is very close to the link to the question

I'm not really sure how to best explain it, perhaps the best way is for others to look at the mobile view and attempt to close a question as duplicate.

I'm also not exactly sure how the view is supposed to look, but I seem to remember this view being considerably cleaner when I used this before.

Comment: hmm I had assumed this was just because my Droid 2 was too old to expect it to operate properly

Comment: We're talking the mobile website view, not the Android app, right? Any chance you could grab a screenshot of what you're seeing?